# Yeoman angular generator looking for local grunt

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gruntjs, yeoman

im trying to create on my linux environment the yeoman angular generator, whenever i execute `yo angular webapp`, an error on the output that says

> Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.

and when i search for `grunt` on my linux environment via `find / -name "grunt"`  this is the output

> /root/.npm/registry.npmjs.org/grunt
>   /root/.npm/grunt
>   /root/sites/node_modules/grunt
>   /root/sites/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt
>   /tmp/npm-2302-5b275c10/registry.npmjs.org/grunt
>   /tmp/npm-11975-b7813b65/registry.npmjs.org/grunt
>   /usr/bin/grunt
>   /usr/lib/node_modules/grunt
>   /usr/lib/node_modules/grunt/bin/grunt
>   /usr/lib/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt
>   /usr/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt

Now, im confused because i've installed Grunt globally how come it will search it for the local copy, why not use the global grunt i just installed?

Answer (score 0):

The grunt documentation say that grunt has to be installed in the project.

The yeoman generator don't install the grunt directly in the project

To solve your issue only do :

```
sudo npm install grunt --save-dev
```

Comment: hello thanks yes i've tried doing this but there are so many grunt dependencies that are needed.. i tried installing them one by one. but isn't it unsual to have all dependencies of grunt not locally available? i mean when i execute that comman wouldn't it be better when i execute 'yo angular webapp' it will resolve automatically its dependencies?

Comment: have your try to do a bower install and/or  a npm install in your project ? If it's still doesn't run you can : clean the npm cache `npm cache clean` and them retry the process